# What is the meaning of this text?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, standard-german

What is the meaning of this text?

> Der Nachmittag ist in diesem Café und in der Straße und daheim in den Wohnungen gefangen. Überall hält man ihn fest und versucht, in ihm zu lesen wie in einem Buch, doch sobald er kann, entgleitet er.

Comment: As you tagged your question with "meaning in context": what is the context? Is this text from a book or what? Do you have an author? And what exactly is your question? Which part of the text is unclear?

Comment: I just can't get the meaning of the last sentence

Comment: @11122222 Is there a certain expression/phrase in that sentence that you don't understand? Or is it about putting together the colon-separated parts?

Answer (score 1):

You correctly tagged this question with *meaning-in-context* but you forgot to add the context. So all we can do is to translate. I hope, this helps:

> The afternoon is trapped in this café and in the street and at home in the apartments. Everywhere people hold it tight and try to read in it like in a book, but as soon as it can, it slips away.

It seems to be a poetic text about an afternoon. Pleople try to hold the afternoon, they even try to read in the afternoon, but the afternoon doesn't like it, and so it slips aways as soon as possible.

Note, that in German *Nachmittag* is a masculine noun, so in German the pronoun referring to it is masculine too (*ihn, ihm, er*), while in English it has to be *it* because an afternoon is not a person.